# Where can you store Pokémon in Black and White?

Tags: pokemon-black-white

I seem to have misplaced my shiny Litwick in Pokémon White. I've looked through all my boxes, checked with the breeding couple, and checked the dreamworld, but I can't seem to find him anymore.

Can we get a list of where that Pokémon could have gone to, and a way to confirm/check if it's there if possible?

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head;

- In your party (unlikely place for a 'lost' Pokémon to be)
- In the PC box (you've checked)
- Daycare (you've checked)
- Dreamworld (you've checked);

  - Also, if anyone has Pokémon still asleep; you might as well wake them up, because [Nintendo is closing Generation 5's Global link](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Global_Link#The_future). Supposedly any Pokémon left in the dream world will be kept on file, ready to wake up, but it is probably best to wake them asap.
- GTS - Deposited as an impossible trade (shame on you).
- Battle Box

  - While accessing the Amanita's PC, below '*Move Pokémon*' and above '*Move Items*' is '**Battle Box**'; that special box used primarily for online battles, this option lets you move Pokémon from your boxes to a special 6-slot box. To me this seems like the most likely culprit if you've checked all other options. Especially if you have gotten used to Generation 6's improved PC box interface that doesn't have a separate menu option exclusively for the battle box.

Answer (score 0):

The only places they could be are:

- PC box
- party
- GTS in the "deposit section
- day care